# difference between 0-x and -x in c++

Tags: c++

I am doing ACM but one problem occured. I just want to know why it is wrong answer when using `part1 = (-b)/ (2 * a);` , but accepted when using `part1 = (0-b)/ (2 * a);`

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while(n--){
        double a,b,c;
        double pd;
        double part1,part2;
        scanf("%lf %lf %lf",&a,&b,&c);
        if (a < 0){
                    a = 0 - a;
                    b = 0 - b;
                    c = 0 - c;
                }
        pd=b*b-4*a*c;
        part1 = (0-b)/ (2 * a);
        if(pd>0){
            part2 = sqrt(pd)/(2 * a);
            printf("x1=%.5lf;x2=%.5lf\n",part1+part2,part1-part2);
        }else if(fabs(pd)<1e-8){
            printf("x1=x2=%.5lf\n",part1);
        }else{
            part2 = sqrt(-pd)/ (2 * a);
            printf("x1=%.5lf+%.5lfi;x2=%.5lf-%.5lfi\n",part1,part2,part1,part2);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
3

1.0 3.0 1.0

2.0 -4.0 2.0

1.0 2.0 8.0
```

Output:

```
x1=-0.38197;x2=-2.61803

x1=x2=1.00000

x1=-1.00000+2.64575i;x2=-1.00000-2.64575i
```

And the source problem is here: http://bailian.openjudge.cn/practice/2707/

Comment: sorry for kind answers,  full code picture is here:http://ww1.sinaimg.cn/large/76eb1075gy1fvkr06v2bpj20md0g13z8.jpg

Comment: Please put the code inline in the question, and also supply the input values you're using, the output you're expecting, and the output you're getting.

Comment: Post code, not link to code

Comment: A good read to increase your odds to have an answer: [mcve].

Comment: sorry for everyone, its my first time to paste my problem here. To be honest, very unfamiliar~. Sorry again for every comment

Comment: All we need to see is for one instance of b and a, what is the difference between part1 calculated with unary negation, and with a subtraction from zero. My hunch is that this is related to strict floating point, but without more details it's only a hunch.

Comment: @kimroniny The site you link to is in Chinese. Not everyone on Stack Overflow is able to understand Chinese.

Comment: @Bathsheba, you're right. The accepted code includes many details about floating point. But now, I really dont know why it is .......

Comment: If you did as I asked you it would be pretty obvious. Help us to help you!

Answer (score 0):

If I translate that page, there is this note, which talks about Java, but supposedly the same applies to C++ solution as well:

> Note that when using Java to do this problem, x1 or x2 may appear In the case of -0, at this time, the negative sign needs to be removed.

`-x` and `0-x` could differ in IEEE-754, if `x` is `0.0`:

- `-x` will be `-0.0`
- `0-x` will be `0.0`

Note the differing sign.